# C++ no instance of constructor matches the argument list argument types are: (std::string, double)

Tags: visual-studio, variables, constructor, instance

Hello i'm learning from a littlebit bad book and when i finished the chapter i didnt find anything about this error and i tried aprox one week to fix it but i didnt afford it so i came here xd. Here some code the "declaration":

```
class variable {
public:
    string name;
    double value;
};
```

And the:

```
    double define_name(string var, double val)
{
    if (is_declared(var)) error(var, "declared twice");
    var_table.push_back(variable(var,val));
    return val;
}
```

This is the code where i got the following error in visual studio underlining the "variable "

**(E0289) no instance of constructor "varaible::variable" matches the argument list**

Comment: You do not have a constructor in your class definition. You have two variables.  You need to declare a constructor that takes two args, string and double.

Comment: How can i do it exactly? Cus i use some constructor but the book didn't explain how it works or something so i dont really know how to declare it.

Comment: maybe i got it :"D 
` 
variable(string variablee, double valuee) {}  
`
 is this good right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message given to you by the compiler is precise and correct. There are two possible fixes here:

1. define the constructor
2. use brace initialization

More details:

Defining a constructor:

```
class variable {
public:
    variable(string n = {}, double v = 0.0) : name{n}, value{v} {}
    string name;
    double value;
};
```

Specifying *reasonable* default values ensures you can use the same constructor for "default" instantiations as well.

As for the second method: all you need to do is use the brace initialization, like the following:

```
    var_table.push_back( {var, val} );
```

The way this works is it matches (by position) the provided initialization list to the members of the struct/class, using defaults (0 for numbers, default-constructors for user-defined types) for the omitted trailing ones, i.e. `var_table.push_back( {var} );` is equivalent to `var_table.push_back( {var, {}} );` which is equivalent to `var_table.push_back( {var, 0.0} );`